# Hanoi Towers - iterative, using lists

Tags: c, list

I want to write standard Hanoi Towers algorythm, using 3 rods, and n discs. But I'd also like to learn how to use lists, so I thought I could combine this.

I thought about creating 3 elements, each representing single rod. Every one of them will have `discs[]` array, and for example if a rod will have 5 discs the array will contain `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` elements.

Ok, I implemented structures etc, but my question is - how to actually solve hanoi towers iterative?

Is it ok to just loop over the rods, and for every disc check where can it go, and move it to the first checked position - and then repeat the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to overcomplicate your life with lists. Use arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DISKS 4 // 10 max
int stacks[3][DISKS];
int sps[3];

void init(int from)
{
  int i;
  sps[2] = sps[1] = sps[0] = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < DISKS; i++)
    stacks[from][i] = DISKS - i; // disk radius
  sps[from] = DISKS;
}

void print(void)
{
  int i, j, k;
  for (i = DISKS - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
      if (sps[j] > i)
      {
        for (k = 0; k < 10 - stacks[j][i]; k++)
          printf(" ");
        for (k = 0; k < 2 * stacks[j][i]; k++)
          printf("x");
        for (k = 0; k < 10 - stacks[j][i]; k++)
          printf(" ");
      }
      else
      {
        printf("                    "); // 10 * 2
      }
      printf("  ");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("_________/\\_________  _________/\\_________  _________/\\_________\n\n");
}

void solve(int to, int from, int cnt)
{
  int other = from ^ to ^ 3;

  if (!cnt) return;

  solve(other, from, cnt - 1);

  stacks[to][sps[to]++] = stacks[from][--sps[from]];
  print();

  solve(to, other, cnt - 1);
}

int main(void)
{
  init(0);
  print();
  solve(2, 0, DISKS);
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/yb2aFf)):

```
         xx                                                       
        xxxx                                                      
       xxxxxx                                                     
      xxxxxxxx                                                    
_________/\_________  _________/\_________  _________/\_________


        xxxx                                                      
       xxxxxx                                                     
      xxxxxxxx                 xx                                 
_________/\_________  _________/\_________  _________/\_________



       xxxxxx                                                     
      xxxxxxxx                 xx                   xxxx          
_________/\_________  _________/\_________  _________/\_________



       xxxxxx                                        xx           
      xxxxxxxx                                      xxxx          
_________/\_________  _________/\_________  _________/\_________



                                                     xx           
      xxxxxxxx               xxxxxx                 xxxx          
_________/\_________  _________/\_________  _________/\_________



         xx                                                       
      xxxxxxxx               xxxxxx                 xxxx          
_________/\_________  _________/\_________  _________/\_________



         xx                   xxxx                                
      xxxxxxxx               xxxxxx                               
_________/\_________  _________/\_________  _________/\_________


                               xx                                 
                              xxxx                                
      xxxxxxxx               xxxxxx                               
_________/\_________  _________/\_________  _________/\_________


                               xx                                 
                              xxxx                                
                             xxxxxx               xxxxxxxx        
_________/\_________  _________/\_________  _________/\_________



                              xxxx                   xx           
                             xxxxxx               xxxxxxxx        
_________/\_________  _________/\_________  _________/\_________



                                                     xx           
        xxxx                 xxxxxx               xxxxxxxx        
_________/\_________  _________/\_________  _________/\_________



         xx                                                       
        xxxx                 xxxxxx               xxxxxxxx        
_________/\_________  _________/\_________  _________/\_________



         xx                                        xxxxxx         
        xxxx                                      xxxxxxxx        
_________/\_________  _________/\_________  _________/\_________



                                                   xxxxxx         
        xxxx                   xx                 xxxxxxxx        
_________/\_________  _________/\_________  _________/\_________


                                                    xxxx          
                                                   xxxxxx         
                               xx                 xxxxxxxx        
_________/\_________  _________/\_________  _________/\_________

                                                     xx           
                                                    xxxx          
                                                   xxxxxx         
                                                  xxxxxxxx        
_________/\_________  _________/\_________  _________/\_________
```

Comment: Thanks for -1, whoever's generosity it was. I included the code to counter the unduly long implementation in the other answer.